# Oracle date & Time difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `RAM` which has four columns, two end date and time and two start date and time, and I want to get the difference between the end and the start. I am using the down query lines and I am getting an error of invalid number, any idea how to correct it?

```
A_STA_DT    A_STA_TIME  B_END_DT    B_END_TIME
6/19/1982   500 7/10/1982   500
7/10/1982   500 8/7/1982    500
8/31/1982   500 9/24/1982   500
9/24/1982   500 11/1/1982   0
5/5/1983    500 6/5/1983    500
7/4/1983    500 7/30/1983   500

SELECT 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR(RAM.B_END_DT, 'dd-mon-yyyy') || RAM.B_END_TIME, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi')ENDDT,  
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR(RAM.A_STA_DT, 'dd-mon-yyyy') || RAM.A_STA_TIME, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi')STADT,
TRUNC(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR(RAM.B_END_DT, 'dd-mon-yyyy') || RAM.B_END_TIME, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi'))-TRUNC(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR(RAM.A_STA_DT, 'dd-mon-yyyy') || RAM.A_STA_TIME, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:Mi'))
FROM RAM
```

Comment: What is the 500 in end_time and start_time?? What does it signify?? Milliseconds?

Comment: 500 is not in the format `hh24:mi:ss` so you're getting an error because you're using an incorrect date format... as you haven't specified what this number means it's quite difficult to help you...

Comment: 0500 is five o'clock in the mooring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are concatenating the date and time, you are not adding a space || ' ' ||.  Second, when you are subtracting the dates, remove the trunc(to_char(.  I think think the below will do what you need.

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RAM.B_END_DT, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(RAM.B_END_TIME, '0999'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24Mi') ENDDT,
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RAM.A_STA_DT, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(RAM.A_STA_TIME, '0999'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24Mi') STADT,
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RAM.B_END_DT, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(RAM.B_END_TIME, '0999'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24Mi') -
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RAM.A_STA_DT, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(RAM.A_STA_TIME, '0999'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24Mi') Diftime
FROM 
    (select to_date('6/19/1982', 'mm/dd/yyyy') A_STA_DT, 500 A_STA_TIME,  to_date('7/10/1982', 'mm/dd/yyyy') B_END_DT, 600 B_END_TIME from dual) RAM
```

Comment: different message;ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: I updated the statement above so that it works for your date now.  Just remove the sub-select at the end for your date.  If your data types aren't date and numeric for the time, you may need a minor tweak.